# Creating a .ped file: how to split values inside my cells creating new columns?

Tags: r, unix, split, genetics

I have a question about the creation of a .ped file for PLINK software.

This is my input file:  a .csv file with 50 rows (with SampleNames) and about 170000 columns (with chr. and physical position of my SNPs). The header will be removed before use.

```
Samples     chr1.pos1  chr1.pos2   ...    chrY...pos100
ID1          -9         G/G                 C/C
ID2          G|T        -9                  GCCCAAATTT|GCCCAAATTTC
ID3          -9         A/A                 A|TGT
ID4
```

I need to split my "G|T", "A/A" in different columns, in order to obtain, for the same "chr1.pos1", the 2 different alleles, like:

```
         chr1.pos1      chr1.pos2   ...    chrY...pos100

Sample   All1     All2      All1     All2          All1         All2
ID1      -9        -9        G        G             C           C
ID2       G         T       -9       -9           GCCCAAATTT    GCCCAAATTTC 
ID3      -9        -9        A        A             A           TGT
ID4
```

How could I solve this issue (Using R or Unix)?
I've ever tried in different ways but it seems that anything is not working...
Really thank you in case of an help!

Francesca

Comment: What do you mean by _The header will be removed before use_ given that in the lower block the header is still there?

Comment: Why do you mention a PED file? The shown data hasn't the mandatory first six columns of a PED file.

Comment: Shall the output really have the inconvenient variable-width column format as shown?

Comment: Hi Armadi, thank you for you kind reply.I mentioned a PED file for two reason.

Comment: As i said, I mentioned a PED file because I have another .csv file with my six mandatory columns for the .ped and its header (FID-IID-MATID-PAT-ID-SEX-STATUS) already filled for the 50 sample. 

The .csv mentioned in my question contains the informations about the alleles (for 167835 SNPs) and I thought that it could be easier:

1. Split the G/G in two different columns (G G, as you can see in the output) 
2. Merge this .csv with the .csv with the six PED columns; 
3.  Remove my header in order to obtain the final PED file.

Comment: For now, I would like to split my columns, as it is shown in the lower block :)
Really thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: It's still unclear to me whether the input file contains the header, what headers the output file shall contain, and whether the input and output files are / shall be in columnar format as shown, which is not a CSV format, or in contrast to what is shown in actual CSV format.

Answer (score 0):

This splits the data if the columns are indeed space separated:

```
awk '{for (i=1; ++i<=NF; ) $i = (split($i, a, "[/|]")>1) ? a[1]" "a[2] : $i" "$i; print}' input_file >output_file
```

For other input separators you can add an [`-F`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html) option after `awk`.